# Why do I get "Operation Not Permitted" when I try (as root) to delete a file that does not have the `restricted` flag set

Tags: macos, sip

I know about SIP, so when I could not delete a file as root from a Mac running El Capitan, I checked for a `restricted` flag using `ls -lOd` and saw that the file had no flags. So why is it that I still cannot delete it? The `ls` command also ruled out the `uchg` and `schg` flags and I'm doing this as root so I don't need to worry about `chown`.

Comment: Where (and what) is the file?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that in addition to the `restricted` *flag*, SIP protection can be invoked on a file by giving it the `com.apple.rootless` *attribute*. Attributes are not shown by `ls -lOd`, you need `ls -l@d` to see them. (Strictly speaking, the `d` option is not necessary, it is there so that when you do `ls` on a directory, you only get information about the directory itself without also getting info on everything in the directory.)

Much more information on this is available [here](https://superuser.com/a/518545/127149).